# How to get current inputqueue programatically in nServiceBus?

Tags: nservicebus

How can I get the current input queue programatically in nServiceBus?

You can set it like this :

```
Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureProperty<MsmqTransport>(t => t.InputQueue, yourDynamicQueue);
```

But how can i Get it ? (without programatically going through the app.config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a dependency to MsmqTransport and access it through the InputQueue property

Comment: Do you have an example doing that ?

Comment: This code is doing just that http://github.com/andreasohlund/NSBManager/blob/master/src/NSBManager.Instrumentation.Core/Inspectors/Transport/MsmqTransportInspector.cs

Comment: Nice, the whole NSBManager thing look promising :) tnx

Comment: NSBManager does look promising, any documentation on how to use it?

Comment: NSBManager is not being actively developed at the moment :(

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the ConfigurationManager's GetSection method to get this straight out of the app.config (or web.config) file, casting the result to the type identified by the configSection entry.

Comment: Yes this is my "last" option if there isnt directly support for it